# Trying to read a float value from MySQL database and encode to JSON to be used with a Google chart

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I have done a few examples like this where i read data from a database and then encode it to JSON so that I can use it in google charts.I know that the PDO always returns a string and up until now I have been able to cast it as an int which worked fine but now I have a column that is a float and I cant seem to get it working.I have tried float_val and a few other things but no luck. The value that I am trying to float is has the column name Load_times and contains values such as 0.11, 0.966, 0.1087 etc. Can anyone help?

Thanks

here is the code that have been using

```
$st = $db->prepare ( "SELECT Chart_Type, SUM(Load_Time) from Timing group by Chart_Type;
                " );

    $st->execute ();

    $rows = array ();
    $flag = true;
    $table = array ();
    $table ['cols'] = array (

            // Labels for chart, these represent the column titles
            array (
                    'label' => 'Chart_Type',
                    'type' => 'string' 
            ),
            array (
                    'label' => 'Load_Time',
                    'type' => 'number' 
            ) 
    )
    ;

    $rows = array ();
    while ( $r = $st->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

        $temp = array ();

        $temp [] = array (
                'v' => ( string ) $r ['Chart_Type'] 
        );

        // Values of each slice

        $temp [] = array (
                'v' => ( float ) $r ['Load_Time'] 

            );

        $rows [] = array (
                'c' => $temp 
        );
    }

    $table ['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode ( $table );
    return $jsonTable;
}
```

when printed the values held $jsontable show that "v":0.

Comment: Why not to narrow your question down to just casting particular value to a float? Why adding PDO and JSON but showing NOT the very value you are trying to cast?

Comment: i know how to cast a value to a float but couldnt get it to work. will edit post now

Comment: Can you provide an example string that converts to 0?  Typically this happens when the string starts with a non-numeric character.  Also, you can avoid explicitly typecasting by passing `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to the `json_encode` call: `$jsonTable = json_encode ($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`.

Comment: @asgallant, the table that it gets its info from has one column of strings such as 'failures' 'time taken' etc and the second column is a float number such as '3.3' '0.011' '1.345' etc

Answer (score 0):

To cast string to float you have use any of the casting operators.

The number is taken straight from your examples:

```
$str = '0.1087';
$float = (float)$str;
var_dump($float);
//float(0.1087)
```

Comment: I had tried something similar to that but it still returns 0's

Comment: here is the code that i had used. it prints out that the value is now a double but all values are zero                                             // Values of each slice
   $converted = (float) $t ['Load_Time'];
   $type = gettype($converted);
   print_r($converted);
   print_r($type);
   
   $temp [] = array (
     'v' => ($converted)
     
    );
   
   $rows [] = array (
     'c' => $temp 
   );
   

  }
  
  $table ['rows'] = $rows;

Comment: i tried to cntrl + k my code in the comment but it didnt do anything, sorry for the format

Comment: The values are stored in an array, in this case the 'LoadTime' array

Comment: I have no idea what 'LoadTime' array is.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In the SQL query I have SUM(Load-Times) but when sorting through values in the array I only had Load_Times.  When I renamed this the float value worked.